# How to type a variant of a function with no optional arguments - with mapped tuple

Tags: typescript

I try to make a typing for a function that has the exact same arguments that the source function, but where none are optional.

I tried to use a mapped tuple, using the logic:

```js
type IFArgs = ArgsN<typeof getFunc>
type IMappedIFArgs = {[N in keyof IFArgs]-?: IFArgs[N]} // The -? removes "optionality"
const getFuncMandatory = <(...args: IMappedIFArgs) => string>getFunc // Error: IMappedIFArgs not a tuple...
```

Where ArgsN comes from the `tsargs` library, and is defined cleverly like this:

```js
export type ArgsN<T extends (...args: any[]) => any> = T extends (...args: infer K) => any ? K : never;
```

According to the 3.1 documentation, the mapped type should also be a tuple, when the source is a tuple.  This seems to be almost the case, when inspecting in VS Code - but not close enough for the compiler to accept it as an argument.  Also, the length of the mapped type returns `2 | 3`, not `3` - which makes sense, but is not what I want.

Any ideas how to make the mapped tuple a valid argument tuple?  Any ideas on how to archive the same using other mechanisms would also be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few of the types you define already exist within TypeScript.

I haven't investigated the differences between what's going on here and what you have, but this seems to work:

```
function getFunc(n:number,s?:string):void{}
type IFArgs = Parameters<typeof getFunc>
type IMappedIFArgs = Required<IFArgs>

const getFuncMandatory = getFunc as ((...args: IMappedIFArgs) => string)
```

See the definitions of these types to compare to your own implementation: [`Parameters`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.3.1/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1474), [`Required`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.3.1/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1431)

Comment: Excellent! This solved my problem.  I'm still not sure why my code did no work, but that is a secondary concern.